# separate numbers with space

Tags: php, numbers, space

I want to separate numbers with space like this: 1 200,12 500 or 2 000 000
instead 2000000...

```
function show_price($id) {
    global $currency_a;
    if(get_option("defaultcurrency")) {
        $curr = $currency_a[get_option("defaultcurrency")][2];
    } else {
        $curr = $currency_a[get_post_meta($id, "currency", true)][2];
    }
    $price = get_post_meta($id, "price", true);
    $currpos = get_option("currpos");
    if($currpos == "1" || !$currpos) {
        return $price."".$curr;
    } elseif ($currpos == "2") {
        return $curr."".$price;
    } elseif ($currpos == "3") {
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

PHP has its very own function for that: `number_format()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Just set the $thousands_sep argument to an empty space instead of the default value. Eg:

```
number_format($number, 0, '.', ' ');
```

Comment: Add it, before the currency is added:
`$price = number_format(get_post_meta($id, "price", true),' ', ' ');`
This only formats numbers, as is says in the documentation (which you should read).

Comment: problem solved! thx for answer!!!
<?php echo number_format(show_price(get_the_ID()), $number,' ', ' '); ?><?php echo $curr = $currency_a[get_post_meta($id, "currency", true)][2]; ?>